# Automate delivery of product codes?

Tags: php, database, paypal, payment

I'm trying to automate the delivery of product codes to customers who have successfully completed a transaction.

I'm trying to think of the most efficient system for handling this.  Essentially our customer pays (currently through PayPal) and we want to display their unique product key to them and email it to them.

Would you just run this is a standard database table with a column for "used" etc?  Or is there a better way to handle the inventory.

Best,
Walker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would generate the key after a success IPN response, store it in the database, display it, and then email it to them. If you are taking from a pool of available product codes I would just mark the product code as used.

Comment: Yeah that sounds fairly simple, I'll give this a shot.